# User role update report

Tags: 7, users

Could you let me know how to check how many users converted from one role to another for a specific period of time (for example how many changed roles from user to superuser from 01/09/2017 to 01/02/2018). How to track user role field change?

Comment: Track what to what exactly, report to whom, in what way, what have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck? Please update your question to clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal doesn't record when a role was changed for a user, at least not out-of-the-box.

A module that can help is the [Role Watchdog](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_watchdog).

Or if you have a store like Ubercart where you sell access, or have expiry dates for roles you can track role changes through available tools there. But it would be overkill to use a store just to track role changes, unless you already have a store installed.